# Can not convert url to html using kanna in swift

Tags: swift, kanna

using Kanna to parse html from url.tried swfitsoup but same problem.

```
 func getContentFromHtml(urlString : String) -> String{
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

     var result = ""

     do {
        let doc = try HTML(url: url, encoding: .utf8)
         for description in doc.xpath("//meta[@property=\"og:description\"]") {
             if let contentDescription = description["content"] {
                 result = contentDescription

             }
         }
     } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
         }
         return result
 }
```

I'm getting 34 urls from google rss(https://news.google.com/rss?hl=ko&gl=KR&ceid=KR:ko) through loop and pass to this method.

but with some urls , it doesn't convert url to html with error code

for example, https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiMWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lnl0bi5jby5rci9fbG4vMDEwM18yMDIwMDMyNTIxNTk0Mzg0NzXSAUNodHRwczovL20ueXRuLmNvLmtyL25ld3Nfdmlldy5hbXAucGhwP3BhcmFtPTAxMDNfMjAyMDAzMjUyMTU5NDM4NDc1?oc=5

this url from rss is getting error.

> `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Kanna.ParseError error 1.)
>   or EncodingMismatch`

but these urls are fine to access.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Print `error` instead of `error.localizedDescription`?

Comment: when I print just error , it prints EncodingMismatch

Comment: What is the full URL you get? For instance, if you have it in Safari, you'll get redirected with locale params, mine got https://news.google.com/rss?hl=fr&gl=FR&ceid=FR:fr for instance.

Comment: Yes . I'm sure. for example,this link with error.
https://news.google.com/rss?hl=ko&gl=KR&ceid=KR:ko

Comment: edited question with some links.

Comment: From the error you get with the long URL (ending with oc=5), the data you get can't be UTF8. The HTTP response says so, but I tried converting it with UTF8 and I couldn't, but UTF16 worked (but I think it's not the best one). So it's normal for Kanna to fail.

Comment: it's very strange. with original rss address in english version, it works fine with all url. Could you explain why with the long URL can't be UTF8?

Comment: See this: https://pastebin.com/cpbNDfQw  It has invalid chara which make the String(data: theDataofTheURLRequest, encoding .utf8) invalid. I didn't check more why.

Comment: @Larme I tested with the long URL (ending with oc=5) with your code and it gives response "HTTPResponse: text/html; charset=UTF-8". but why it is failing?

Comment: It says it’s utf8 but it isn’t. What can I say ?